# Plotting consecutive series (e.g. concentration, time) of a curve in 3d rstudio

Tags: r, graph, 3d

I'm running samples on a machine where my output is a graph of a unitless coefficient `y` vs speed `x`. I vary the concentration of a given compound to discover how the curve changes dependent on concentration `z`. Is there a package that can plot 3d graphs of data set up in this way, i.e. as series?

I find that the commonly used packages for 3d plots in rstudio (lattice, scatterplot3d, rgl etc) only seem to work when variables are equally sized vectors (i.e. each point is one sample):

[image: common example x,y,z data setup]

My data looks more like this where each "slice" so to speak on the z-axis represents one sample:

[image: example series data]

I can plot it fairly easily in Excel using surface plots but the graphs there are shitty, ugly and inflexible.

Best example of the graph I'm aiming for is this:

> [image: nytimes sample 3d plot]
>
> Source: https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2015/03/19/upshot/3d-yield-curve-economic-growth.html?ref=economy&abt=0002&abg=0

Following is an example of my data. First column contains x-values (speed), first row contains z-values (concentration), everything else is y-values (arbitrary unitless coefficient). First cell (0) is therefore not part of the data.

```
structure(list(...1 = c(0, 1.17721e-08, 1.48056166666667e-08, 
1.86639666666667e-08, 2.35371333333333e-08, 2.96521333333333e-08
), ...2 = c(0.3, 0.000326036, 0.000789132, 0.00132642, 0.00196508, 
0.00272198), ...3 = c(3, 0.00038811, 0.000915256, 0.00152748, 
0.00224812, 0.00311174), ...4 = c(6, 0.000289036, 0.000692406, 
0.00115582, 0.00169984, 0.00234574), ...5 = c(15, 0.000266082, 
0.000647076, 0.00109054, 0.00161336, 0.00224112), ...6 = c(30, 
0.000361498, 0.000818448, 0.00134682, 0.00196732, 0.00271138), 
...7 = c(100, 0.000296934, 0.000714832, 0.0012111, 0.0018063, 
0.0025273)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I stored the 'dput()' as 'example.data' and ran the following to get this error message:

```
#Store x and y as vectors, z as matrix 
> x <- c(example.data[-1,1])
> y <- c(example.data[1,-1])
> z <- as.matrix(example.data[-1,-1], nrow = 5, ncol = 6)
> persp3d(x, z, y)
Error in rgl.surface(x = NULL, y = list(...2 = 0.3, ...3 = 3, ...4 = 6,  : 
'y' length != 'x' rows * 'z' cols
```

What am I doing wrong here? x and y have same number of rows and columns, respectively as the matrix z

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly. Also, please include code you've already tried, as otherwise this is *"asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library"*, which is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: *"only seem to work when variables are equally sized vector"* is confusing, as I know of no plotting engine (in R or otherwise) that will plot (2d, 3d) when the variables are of unequal length (notwithstanding R's "recycling" concept).

Comment: Thanks for the edit @jtweeder.

Comment: @r2evans I've tried with the rgl package so far but honestly haven't got anything worth showing. What I mean by unequal length is that one sample is defined by 80 points in the x,y-plane while the z-axis might only have a length of 10, i.e. 10 samples of varying concentration plotted in series. Does that make sense? I apologise if the question is off-topic

Comment: If you are doing a 3D plot (e.g., `rgl`), then the x, y, and z vector must have the same length; otherwise, if you plot x,y,z for those with all three, where (on the z-axis) do you plot the x,y pairs that don't have a corresponding z? I think that part is really confusing to me.

Comment: I think this question will really benefit from providing *real R data*, not an image of concept data. Please provide the output from `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)` that provides a sample of the data you expect to use. (For example, I don't know what `y1,1` means as a *value*. While explaining that might be useful, it is just as relevant to get real data.)

Comment: I hope the provided data makes it clearer. What I was trying to explain with the `y1,1` thing was just that any y-value belongs to a specific x- and z-value e.g. y(x1,z1).

Comment: The data shows a 6x6 frame, but it isn't clear how you intend to map the three dimensions. Is one of the columns `x`? Is it meaningful that the first row of data is many orders of magnitude larger than the other rows?

Comment: @r2evans, the first row represents values for one axis (e.g. 'z'), first column represents values for e.g. 'x'-values while the rest of the data represents 'y'-values. I may have found a solution using the 'persp3d' function, will update post if relevant.

Comment: If you are using the whole array as the `z` value, then it is typically better to store the `x` and `y` values in separate vectors and store this `z` as a `matrix`, not a `data.frame` with x/y somohow integrated.

Comment: @r2evans I did as suggested but got the error message shown above. Sorry for the stupid questions, I'm on a steep learning curve here

Comment: You need to check your variables. When you use this code, `x` is still a `tbl_df` (`data.frame)` and not a vector because of the way that `tibble` is subsetting the `tbl_df` for you. If you do `x <- x[[1]]` and then `rgl::persp3d(x,y,z)`, you should get a plot. (You'll need to use `as.numeric` on `y` as well, similar reasons.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your sample data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(...1 = c(0, 1.17721e-08, 1.48056166666667e-08, 
1.86639666666667e-08, 2.35371333333333e-08, 2.96521333333333e-08
), ...2 = c(0.3, 0.000326036, 0.000789132, 0.00132642, 0.00196508, 
0.00272198), ...3 = c(3, 0.00038811, 0.000915256, 0.00152748, 
0.00224812, 0.00311174), ...4 = c(6, 0.000289036, 0.000692406, 
0.00115582, 0.00169984, 0.00234574), ...5 = c(15, 0.000266082, 
0.000647076, 0.00109054, 0.00161336, 0.00224112), ...6 = c(30, 
0.000361498, 0.000818448, 0.00134682, 0.00196732, 0.00271138), 
...7 = c(100, 0.000296934, 0.000714832, 0.0012111, 0.0018063, 
0.0025273)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

It's typically best to keep the data as a `matrix`, and for this to keep `x`, `y`, and `z` separate. Your initial subsetting would have worked except that `tibble` intentionally keeps it a `frame`-like thing, as opposed to a "normal" `data.frame`'s single column/row subsetting and its need for [`dat[...,drop=FALSE]`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) to avoid class conversion.

```r
x <- dat[-1,1][[1]]
y <- as.numeric(dat[1,-1])
z <- as.matrix(dat[-1,-1])
rgl::persp3d(x,y,z)
```

[image: 3d plot]

You could also have converted to a `matrix` *first*, then you wouldn't have been exposed to `tibble`'s protection here.

```r
dat <- as.matrix(dat)
x <- dat[-1,1]
y <- dat[1,-1]
z <- dat[-1,-1]
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much, I just got a lot cleverer